# calculate resonancefrequence RLC||C2

Tags: frequency, resonance

I try to find the formula for resonance frequence in a circuit
in series R-L-C1 and parallel to that C2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg6ND8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know only the formula for normal RLC-circuits its 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi*\sqrt{L*C}}
$$

My derivation so far(maybe someone could say something to it):

$$
Z_E = R+j\omega*L-\frac{j}{\omega*C} = R + j(\frac{\omega^2LC-1}{\omega * C})\\
Z_{C_2} = - \frac{j}{\omega C_2} \\
Z_G = \frac{Z_{C_2} * Z_E}{Z_{C_2} + Z_E} = \frac{-\frac{j}{\omega C_2} * (R + j(\frac{\omega^2LC-1}{\omega * C}))}{-\frac{j}{\omega C_2} + R + j(\frac{\omega^2LC-1}{\omega * C})}
$$ 
 From here I think I have to split up the imaginary part from real part and than I can set it to 0?

Comment: Draw your circuit or embed a diagram for clarity.

Comment: Think how that formula (for LC) is derived. What happens at resonance ? Write down the parallel impedance Zc(s) and Zl(s). When you arrive at the formula you have, do the same for the RLC // C circuit. Hint: it has 2 resonance peaks.

Comment: And remember the general DEFINITION of "resonance".

Comment: Go look up how a crystal resonator works - it has exactly the same characteristic parallel and series resonant points. You might also try simulating it in LTSpice.

Comment: I know on resonance X_L = -X_C means imaginary part goes 0, I tryed to derive it myself but now I run out of time and need a quick solution i've heared derivation ends in a quadratic equation and there I get w1 and w2.

Comment: *but now I run out of time and need a quick solution* Hmm, if you would have started yesterday you would have plenty of time. If you do this once properly (taking your time) then next time you will have the solution in less time.

Comment: i see, to be honest in my comment was a big mistake :/

Comment: Answer to your last sentence: Yes.

Comment: [**Here's**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrtu95oto3ptenf/Resonance2.png?dl=0) a clue.

Comment: Honesty isn't a mistake; attitude is.

Comment: sorry dont understand the clue, i already measured  it and know the graphs and frequency, i am searching for mathematical validation, but thanks for your help

Comment: Mathematical validation: As you have mentioned with your last sentence. Have you access to a SYMBOLIC analyzer program? It can do the math for you.

Comment: Mathematical validation is very involved. I have found a book with the correct results. Are you interested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've tried and seem honest I will give an answer.

There are two resonant frequencies. There is a the series resonant frequency which exclusively depends only on L and C1 and there is a parallel resonant frequency that depends on L and the combination of C1 and C2. Here's my take on it: -

The impedance is \$\dfrac{(R + sL + \frac{1}{sC_1})\frac{1}{sC_2}}{R + sL + \frac{1}{sC_1}+\frac{1}{sC_2}}\$

That's basically product over sum as you did.

It reduces to Z = \$\dfrac{s^2 + s\frac{R}{L} + \frac{1}{LC_1}}{sC_2(s^2 + s\frac{R}{L} + \frac{1}{L}(\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}))}\$

Half a sheet of regular notepad paper is all you need providing you aim for the standard format solution (yes I did use algebra rather than a math tool!).

So, the two resonant frequencies are \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC_1}}\$

And \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC_S}}\$ where \$C_S\$ is the two capacitors in series.

Those formulas numerically produce natural resonant frequencies of 6.059 kHz (series) and 12.831 kHz (parallel) and, if you look at my simulation below....

[image]

... it ties in with the math.

I made the above plot with R at 2 ohms just so that it would "amplify" the two resonant frequencies with minimal error because working with jw isn't quite the same as working with s when there is a fair bit of damping. The plot is a transfer function plot, not an impedance plot so don't be confused by the overall rising trend. The impedance will have an overall falling trend due to the "sC2" in the denominator.

Comment: Hi really thanks for your answer, but there must be two solutions the graph crosses the Y axxis two times, the formula must be a quadratic equation, I think.

Comment: There's a quadratic in the numerator and there's a quadratic in the denominator.

Comment: I did make one mistake - I didn't mean C1 to be in parallel with C2 - I meant in series.

Comment: Have to go to the uni now, but i will review in the evening

Comment: I've even simulated it and got the same results.

Comment: Andy aka, I cannot agree to the formulas as well as the simulation results. My results: 6.96 kHz and 11.1 kHz. Example: For w=1/sqrt(LC1) the numerator is not zero.

Comment: @LvW I'm not sure what you did - I lowered damping ratio quite a bit so that the bode plot from my sim pretty much predicts the natural resonant points. Basically for the series calculation I get 6059 Hz by using only 3mH and the 230nF capacitor - series resonance is always going to be independent of the 66 nF cap. For parallel, the effective capacitance is 66nF in series with 230 nF = 51.28 nF which gives a frequency of 12.831 kHz.

Comment: Well - perhaps we have two different definitions for resonance? My definition is based on a real impedance (resp. admittance). That means: Imag. part of Z(jw)=0. This identical with phase=0. In this case, no modification of the circuit was necessary. However, the quadratic formula for the frequency (for the case Im=0) is rather long. By the way: What shows your plot? Output voltage of 2 ohms in series with the given circuitry?

Comment: @LvW remember I'm only using my sim (micro-cap) to demonstrate that my formula was correct and it is the formula that embeds everything about the impedance. I went for \$\omega_n\$ because there should be no dispute to what I'm referring to. I used the circuit as shown in the OP's question with R at 1 ohm then an additional 1 ohm to ground. I plotted the voltage across the 1 ohm to ground i.e. I developed a circuit that gave a transfer function so I could see the peaks. Series resonant clearly is at -6.02 dB as you'd expect with a potential divider of two 1 ohm resistors at series resonance.

Comment: @Andy aka, the emain question is the DEFINITION you have used - and I think, it is not compatible with the commonly used definition: Frequencies, where the phase shift is zero (imag. part=0). You have identified the "peaks", but they are identical to resonance for simple LC circuits only. This can be verified by comparing your formulas with formulas which apply to equivalent circuits for a crystal.

Comment: @LvW I'm struggling to see YOUR problem. I HAVE calculated the impedance and, from this you can thoroughly determine everything that is important about that impedance. In order to PROVE that my formula is correct I have estimated the values of the natural frequencies and used a simulation with very low damping ratio to categorically prove that those NATURAL (not damped or ringing) frequencies exactly equal the values derived from the formula. This proves the formula is correct and, a correct formula allows you to calculate damped and ringing frequencies.

Comment: If you get different numbers then please make an answer of it and I'll be the first to admit I'm wrong. @LvW but other than what I've done above I cannot see what point you are trying to make. In addition I'll point out that this was the route that the op was heading and I've just helped him along the way. Are you saying that in order to answer this correctly you want me to calculate the frequencies where the phase shift is zero?

Comment: @LvW you also said in an earlier comment that you "cannot agree to the formulas" - which formulas are you talking about?

Comment: @Andy aka, I repeat the main question: What is the DEFINITION you have used? You have mentioned "natural frequencies", is THIS your definition? I have used the - as far as I know - commonly used definition: Im(Z)=0 (or zero phase shift). Regarding your formulas: Z(s) is correct, but I doubt if the derived formulas for resonance are in accordance with the "correct" definition. Do you know what I mean? Comment: The definition with Im=0 is relevant for a crystal in the feedback path of an oscillator, for example.

Comment: @Andy aka, I must admit that in most books/articles about resonant frequencies of a crystal we see both formulas as given by you. HOWEVER, these formulas are very good approximations for very small Rs values only (as is applicable for crystals). But in the present case, we have Rs=100 ohms. In this case, there is a considerable difference between these (simplified) formulas and the frequency where the phase shift is zero. Can easily verified by simulation.

Comment: My sole aim was to derive the Z formula. That formula can be converted to jw and the zero phase angle frequency found but, I have not taken that step. I tried to help the OP by taking his general approach that he gave up on - finding the formula for the impedance in terms of the two standard formulii (numerator and denominator) was my aim. I only simulated the peaks with very low damping ratio (R effectively 2 ohms) in order to demonstrate that the peak and trough were in fact correct as per the undamped peak and trough as implied in my formula.

Comment: @Andy aka, I see your point. To end this discussion I have described my view in a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

In his question user89709 requests some help in finding the resonant frequency for a given circuit. It is clear that the answer requires at first to find the frequency-dependent **impedance Zin** of the circuit. I think, this first part of the task was fulfilled (see corresponding formulas from user89709 as well as in Andy aka`s detailed answer).

But now the question remains how to find the resonant frequencies from this expression for Zin. Hence, we need the **DEFINITION** of the condition we call "**resonance**".

According to my understanding and knowledge, "resonance" is defined for the case where capacitive and inductive parts of Zin cancel each other - with other words: The remaining part of Zin is **pure resistive**, which is identical to the requirement: **Zero phase** shift between V across the circuit and I into the circuit.

In most cases we have small resistive losses and this condition is (nearly) equivalent to the maximum (parallel resonance) or the minimum (series resonance) of the impedance Zin. However, if the resistive part R cannot be neglected in comparison to the capacitive and/or inductive parts of Zin (in the relevant frequency region) we can observe remarkable differences between maxima/minima and the corresponding zero-phase crossings.

Hence, for finding the resonant frequencies we have to identify the imaginary part Im(Zin) and solve the equation **Im(Zin)=0** for the frequencies fo1 and fo2. This is a rather time-consuming task. The numerical solution can be found in some textbooks.

For the purpose of graphical visualization, I have performed a computer simulation for the given circuit using an AC current source (1A). The voltage across the circuit is identical to the impedance Zin. As we can see, there are considerable differences between the maxima/minima and the zero crossings of the phase function (which are identical to the wanted resonant frequencies).

**EDIT**: Here are two **references** (defining the resonant points):

Fig. 2 in
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/726

Fig. 7 and 8 in
http://www.foxonline.com/pdfs/xtaldesignnotes.pdf

[image]

Comment: Makes sense +1.